# Reiniciar Nivel

Tags: c#, unity2d

Tengo la siguiente pregunta estoy haciendo un Juego en Unity 3d (2D)
Bueno me surgio la necesidad de crear un reiniciar nivel "no cuando muera si no en cualquier momento pueda reiniciar el nivel ya que hay unos espacios pequeños donde el Jugador no podra entrar esto fue creado intencionalmente lo que quiero es cuando el jugador se quede atrapado pueda reinciar el nivel"

Este es el codigo que uso para llamar los niveles

```html
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class EscenaLogica : MonoBehaviour {
    public AudioSource Musica;
    public AudioSource Perdiste;
    public JugadorLogica Jugador;
    public GameObject PuntoInicio;
    public GameObject[] NivelPrefab;
    private int IndiceDeNiveles;
    private GameObject ObjetoNivel;
    private GameObject moneda;
    public int puntaje;
    public Text TextoDeJuego;
    public bool YaSeEscucho = false;
 // Use this for initialization
 void Start () {
        Musica.Play();
        IndiceDeNiveles = 0;
        ObjetoNivel = Instantiate(NivelPrefab[IndiceDeNiveles]);
        ObjetoNivel.transform.SetParent(this.transform);
  
 }
 
 // Update is called once per frame
 void Update () {
        TextoDeJuego.text = "Nivel" + (IndiceDeNiveles + 1) +
            "\nPuntaje: " + puntaje;
        if (Jugador.Perdiste)
        {
            if(!YaSeEscucho){
                Perdiste.Play();
                YaSeEscucho = true;
            }
            TextoDeJuego.text = "Nivel" + (IndiceDeNiveles + 1) +
            "\nPuntaje: " + puntaje+ "\nPerdiste Presione R para reiniciar el nivel";

            if (Input.GetKeyDown("r"))
            {
                puntaje = 0;
                Jugador.JugadorBody.constraints = RigidbodyConstraints2D.None;
                Jugador.JugadorBody.constraints = RigidbodyConstraints2D.FreezeRotation;

                Jugador.gameObject.transform.position = PuntoInicio.transform.position;
                Destroy(ObjetoNivel);
                ObjetoNivel=Instantiate(NivelPrefab[IndiceDeNiveles]);
                ObjetoNivel.transform.SetParent(this.transform);
                Jugador.Perdiste = false;
                YaSeEscucho = false;
            }
        }
        if (Jugador.SiguienteNivel)
        {
            TextoDeJuego.text = "Nivel" + (IndiceDeNiveles + 1) +
               "\nNivel Completado \nPresione R para  el siguiente  nivel";

            if (IndiceDeNiveles == NivelPrefab.Length - 1)
            {
                TextoDeJuego.text = "Completaste el Juego" + "\n presione R para volver a iniciar";
            }
            if (Input.GetKeyDown("r"))
            {
                Jugador.JugadorBody.constraints = RigidbodyConstraints2D.None;
                Jugador.JugadorBody.constraints = RigidbodyConstraints2D.FreezeRotation;
                Jugador.gameObject.transform.position = PuntoInicio.transform.position;
                if (IndiceDeNiveles == NivelPrefab.Length - 1)
                {
                    Destroy(ObjetoNivel);
                    IndiceDeNiveles = 0;
                    ObjetoNivel = Instantiate(NivelPrefab[0]);
                    ObjetoNivel.transform.SetParent(this.transform);
                    Jugador.SiguienteNivel = false;
                }
                else {
                    Destroy(ObjetoNivel);
                    IndiceDeNiveles += 1;
                    ObjetoNivel = Instantiate(NivelPrefab[IndiceDeNiveles]);
                    ObjetoNivel.transform.SetParent(this.transform);
                    Jugador.SiguienteNivel = false;
                 
                }

            }
        }
  
 }
}
```

Estaba usando esto para recargar el nivel el problema es que si por ejemplo esta en el nivel 2 y lo reinicio me devuelve al nivel 1

```html
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ReloadLogica : MonoBehaviour {

 // Use this for initialization
 void Start () {
  
 }
 
 // Update is called once per frame
 void Update () {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Mouse0))
        {
            Application.LoadLevel(Application.loadedLevel);
        }
  
 }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

prueba con esto:  `SceneManager.LoadScene( SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name );`

y recuerda agregar esta libreria:

> using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

Comment: Hola,amigo gracias por tu ayuda ese line al probe y da lo mismo me devuleve hasta el Nivel 1

Comment: tienes los niveles segmentados en diferentes escenas, verdad?, por que si tienes todo los niveles en la misma escena es normal que vuelva al nivel 1, en el caso que cada nivel tenga su propia scena prueba esa misma linea y remplaza lo que esta dentro del parentesis por un string con el nombre de la escena